# Powershell infinite loop and returning unexpected results

Tags: powershell, shell-script

**Script**

---

```
PS C:\folder>$a=@(100,001,10,101,002,11)
```

---

```
$arrayCount=$a.count

for ($i=0; $i -le $arrayCount; $i+=3) {
    $oldNumber=$a[$i]
    $oldNumber="{0:d3}" -f $oldNumber
    $newNumber=$a[$i+1]
    $newNumber="{0:d3}" -f $newNumber
    $folderNumber=$a[$i+2]
    $folderNumber="{0:d2}" -f $folderNumber

    Get-ChildItem -file -filter $oldNumber.ext |

            ForEach-Object {
            $newFile=$newNumber+" (BRP-16-"+$newNumber+"-F-06K48b-SC-A-CC-"+$folderNumber+")"
            
           #Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $newFile
            
            echo $_.name
            echo $newFile
            echo ""
    }
}
```

**Results**

---

```
100.ext
100 (BRP-16-100-F-06K48b-SC-A-CC-10)

101.ext
100 (BRP-16-100-F-06K48b-SC-A-CC-10) #expected: 101 (BRP-16-101-F-06K48b-SC-A-CC-11)

100.ext
100 (BRP-16-100-F-06K48b-SC-A-CC-10) #loop starts repeating

101.ext
100 (BRP-16-100-F-06K48b-SC-A-CC-10)

...
```

**Problem**

---

1. The loop is repeating itself infinitely.
2. After the first loop (which runs is as expected), the second loop continues to use partial information from the first loop. That is, instead of using `a[4]=002` for the `$newNumber` in the second loop, it continues to use `a[1]=001` for `$newNumber`. Similarly, instead of using `a[5]=11` for loop 2, it uses `a[2]=10` for loop 2.

Comment: use the debugger.  how anyone can code without one is beyond me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why, but adding double quotes around`$oldNumber.ext` in `Get-ChildItem -file -filter "$oldNumber.ext"` solved the problem.

**Infinite Loop Problem**

---

The infinite loop was caused by this line:

```
for ($i=0; $i -le $arrayCount; $i+=3) {
```

The `-le` should have been `-lt`